# Invert Selection checkbox

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I want to use a checkbox to invert the current checkboxbar selection, the code now basically works, but I hope that when the checkboxbar is all selected or not, the status of the first checkbox will respond correctly.

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 x = {a, b, c, d};
 y = x;
 Column[{
   Row[{"first", Spacer[16], 
     Dynamic@Checkbox[Dynamic[y], {Complement[x, y], x}]}], 
   Row[{"second", Spacer[6], Dynamic[CheckboxBar[Dynamic[y], x]]}],
   Dynamic[{x, y, Complement[x, y]}]
   }]
 ]
```

current state

[image] [image]

Correct state
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want to do :

```
 DynamicModule[{x, y, inverted}, x = {a, b, c, d};
 y = x;
 inverted = False;
 Column[{
   Row[{"first", Spacer[16], 
     Checkbox[
      Dynamic[inverted, (y = Complement[x, y]; inverted = #) &]]}],
   Row[{"second", Spacer[6], CheckboxBar[Dynamic[y], x]}]}]]
```

[image]